# Let $a$,$b\in \mathbb{Z}$, not both zero. Prove set $S$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-writing

Let $a$,$b\in \mathbb{Z}$, not both zero. Let $S = \{n\in\mathbb{Z}|n=ax+by\text{ for some }x,y\in\mathbb{Z}\}$ Let $d=(a,b)$. Prove that $S$ is the set of all integer multiples of d.

Comment: @Alex I see you're new to the site. Usually, you want to provide some context when you ask questions on here as well as what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

This is well known basic algebra problem. And since there's already been similar posts about this problem, I ll give you a simple, but very useful hint.

**Hint**: Try to use Euclid's algorithm